# Is there a way to use the ReadOnlySpan<char> overloads for StringBuilder and TryParse methods in a netstandard2.0 class library?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, tryparse, c#-7.2, system.memory

I have a NetStandard2.0 class library. I have imported the `System.Memory` nuget package, which means I can use `Span<T>` inside it. That's well and good, but the nuget package doesn't seem to include the `ReadOnlySpan<char>` overloads for `StringBuilder` and the `TryParse()` methods for other primitive types.

If I could upgrade to netstandard21, I would do that, and this problem would go away, but I can't for reasons beyond my control.

This code works in a `netcoreapp2.2` program, but not a netstandard20 class library, even with `System.Memory` as a dependency:

```
public static int GetIbanIntValueForCharacter(ReadOnlySpan<char> span)
{
    // Stuff

    if (int.TryParse(span, out var val))
    {
        return val;
    }

    // More stuff
}
```

Is there another nuget package that I can reference that brings span support to `StringBuilder` and `TryParse` to netstandard20 libraries?

Comment: These overloads are not supported in .NET Framework, and thus they're not present in .NET Standard 2 either (note that no version of .NET Framework implements .NET Standard 2.1). They can't be implemented separately because these types are part of the system libraries, so even if .NET Standard pretended they existed they'd still fail to work at runtime when running on .NET Framework. In theory equivalent `Span` methods could be implemented on .NET Framework, but then they would still not be present on the original classes, so you'd still need to multi-target anyway.